# fb:promt-permission gives me a link, I need a direct popup

Tags: python, django, facebook

I'm using Django/Python , I need to ask the user for permission to let me put feeds ( ideally oneliners which was not working so I thought to use full streams) into the user profile.

Would you like to receive email from our application?

This is giving me a hyper link which I click and it shows me the permission box. What is need for this to happen is after the end of the game it automatically prompts for it and then publishes. Which isn't really working.

Thanks :)

Comment: Without showing us some code, and giving more details than it "isn't really working", this is an unanswerable question.

Comment: Currently I'm using the fbml 

<fb:prompt-permission perms="publish_stream">Would you like to receive email from our application?</fb:prompt-permission>

I need to create a automatic popup to prompt the user instead of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the javascript [FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog) method.

it takes an optional callback function to which it passes whether the permission was allowed or not, so you could call FB.Connect.streamPublish in that callback if the permission was granted.

Comment: stupid SO wouldn't let me post more than one link. FB.Connect.streamPublish docs are here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.streamPublish

Comment: I tried this, now its working fine :) Facebook.showPermissionDialog('publish_stream,read_stream');